# Room Persistent Library Dynamic TableName

Tags: android-room

I am trying to query data from table of unknown name (will be downloaded from server) but wit known structure - Column names using room. I created some Template Entity And DAO Now I am trying To implement Query in new table but i keep getting errors My Query
    @Query("SELECT * FROM (:Table")
    List getAll(String Table);
I ave read somewere tat table names and column names can not be variables in functions, so is tere any workaround of my problem, or I sould stick to good old SqliteOpenelper.

Comment: Have you got any solution?? for the above Question... can you update..

Comment: no I did not , honestly i abandoned android project

Answer (score 1):

You can use Room's @RawQuery. It will allow you write Query in runtime